# React error: Each child in a list should have a unique “key” prop

Tags: reactjs

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F6Yz.png)

Answer (score 2):

When mapping in react, react needs to identify each component by its unique key, so when user interact with component it will know exactly where to address, at the div container you can pass as key={showroom_id} ...

PS, react uses className instead of class, hence you are getting another error on top